# cordova plugin add error

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-3, cordova-cli

[image]

Hi, I am facing issue in adding any plugins for cordova project I tried setting up proxy too but still I am unable to install plugins.

Comment: Did you try to install something else using a different package-manager? firewall-issues is likely to be the problem here. Or start your shell with admin-rights is also worth a try.

Comment: There is firewall issue only I m in an oraganization's proxy server. I tried setting up proxy but still same error TiMEOUT

Comment: can you remember how you solved this ?

Comment: according to this there was some changes http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getting-404-error-when-trying-to-add-cordova-plugin/25529  and old versions are hard to maintain

Comment: This still happens